# Failed executing DbCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, mysql-workbench

I have this problem after trying to update database,using IdentityDbContext

```
Failed executing DbCommand (8ms)
[Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
```

```
CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserRoles` (
    `UserId` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
    `RoleId` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`, `RoleId`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `AspNetRoles` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MySqlWorkBench.

Comment: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes i have this problem too

Comment: Well 767 + 767 = 1534 so it's not clear why that's happening. But 767 sounds very long for an ID anyway, can you not make it shorter?

Comment: builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(760)); i try this but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fistly you can check table in db. If there was table, you can alter table